# Will coronavirus go down the history as a disease of biblical proportions?

Tags: disease

30 million people are affected by coronavirus as of today and numbers are still increasing. We are not sure when it will end.
Do you think coronavirus will be remembered as a disease of biblical proportions?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations.  Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. In particular, we discourage opinion based ("do you think") questions, and questions about the future "will be remembered"). Is it possible to revise this question within those constraints?

Comment: It is a valid question. Delete it if you wish...but that will make this forum useless to me. I will leave.

Comment: There are many valid questions that are not in scope for history stack exchange.  Questions about the future, and subjective questions are out of scope.

Comment: @SacrificialEquation : Welcome. History.SE is not quite a forum, its aim is to address questions that can be answered in an objective way. Speculations about the future perception of a current panemic doesn't fit, but you could probably rephrase this by asking, e.g., how Covid19 compares to past pandemics. In the process, think about providing a definition for "biblical proportions"...

Comment: People can only be led to believe such nonsense because they forgot the sense of what were real plagues variola, tuberculosis, polio, or the black death itself. Compared with these, covid is less than nothing. Even untreated covid is just ~ 2 or 3 times more lethal than common flu, and with early treatment covid kills even less than flu. Moreover, USA CDC said that twice as much children died from flu than from covid this year.  Compare with polio or variola.

Comment: @Luiz That seems like a valid objective answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because speculation about possible other events that could out-bible corona in the near future is bad luck

Comment: @mart  This question has valid answers. I oppose unfair closing of this question...

Comment: @SacrificialEquation If you accept to take remarks into account and precise your question, it may become valid and avoid closure. Otherwise, sorry, but your "opposition" won't be enough for the site to change its rules...

Comment: @SacrificialEquation actually I was joking and not voting to close (there's a "close" button for those of us with enough reputation o  this site).

Comment: But I think the question is bad because it invites speculation, not solid answers. Simply put we can't know if a working, reliable vaccine is allready in use or years away, we don't know if next year millions will die from antibiotics-resistant bacterial diseases or some pleistocene macrovirus straight from the melted permafrost or whatever.

Comment: This can't be legitimately answered because "biblical proportions" has no defined meaning.

Answer (score 1):

People can only be led to believe such nonsense because they forgot the sense of what were real plagues variola, tuberculosis, polio, or the black death itself. Compared with these, covid is less than nothing, totally, utterly, irrelevant. People from just 100y ago would laugh on our face about our stress about it.

Even untreated covid is just ~ 2 or 3 times more lethal than common flu, and with early treatment covid kills even less than flu. (all politicians still pushing against early treatment are corrupted crisis-surfers or guilty of high treason). Moreover, USA CDC said that twice as much children died from flu than from covid this year. Compare with polio or variola.

If covid would appear in 1800, before viruses were known, people would not even notice, because the proportion of old people were smaller, and the increase of deaths would not be noticeable. Even if the proportion of old people were the same as today, a few % more deaths is just a bad year. Even in Italy, that the media painted as hell on earth, 600K people die every year, and 2020 was not even the worse flu season in terms of deaths from respiratory diseases, as a few years ago there were more respiratory deaths in the usual flu season (2017-18?). Besides, Italy today is an unbelievably geriatric country, with one of the worse intensive case units per capita values in Europe.

Variola could kill between 20% and 70%, Tuberculosis ~20%, Black Death ~30%. And note that such averages hide the fact that some places are more affected than others.

A French friend has land near Castres, Languedoc. On her land, there are ruins from a XVII or XVIII c. village, around 5 houses with some extra buildings, which they know to have been suddenly abandoned. People assume that it was due to some war, but this could easily happen due to a variola or tuberculosis epidemic - all of them died, or at least so few people were left that it become impractical to live in the village. Some years ago on English TV there were a report about a four-families hamlet abandoned on early XX c due to tuberculosis. They showed a bronze plaque placed there by relatives stating that all 5 members of the same family died together.

These are real "biblical plagues", not anything that is even remotely comparable with or in the same order of magnitude as the usual flu.

Mostly, large cities could not have positive natural population growth until modern sanitation and medicine were developed - the cities had to have a constant influx of migrants to keep their population. It is hard to separate the effects of sanitation, medicine, and vaccination, but having many cities with millions of people where the population still grows naturally is a modern phenomenon. There are even some people who wonder how we could keep cities such as NYC in existence if variola were to reappear, or if a 100%-resistant tuberculosis were to appear.

Comment: This marches merrily through "wrong" and right on into "dangerous". The first wave of the 1918 flu pandemic killed about 75k Americans, while the second killed about 300,000. We aren't through the first wave (praying there will be no later ones), and 200,000 Americans have died. Our population was about a third of today's then, but clearly the effect is of the same order of magnitude down on the business end where it matters, and its still just getting started. As the tortoise says, slow but steady wins the race.

Comment: nCov dangers were surely overstated, so far. This 'emerging disease' is 'current events'! But apart from a question asking for speculating about the future, we see here an answer that indeed speculates a lot with 'what ifs' — even without sources! Please keep the answer more 'historical', add sources etc. Eg try to find an updated version of this outdated visual https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-8120631/Visual-timeline-coronavirus-compares-historys-deadly-pandemics.html found on several sites (the 'chosen source' just had the most pixels) preferably accounting for demographic changes?

Comment: T.E.D. Spanish flu was from 10 to 30 times as lethal as ordinary flu, barely in the same order of magnitude. And he is asking if covid is "biblical", so we have to compare with the big ones, not with spanish flu. Nobody today remember the spanish flu as "biblical", even because at that time they still had the big ones.

Comment: How many upvotes/downvotes on this answer, I don't have enough rep to see